# Remove option to upload image in CKEDITOR 5 with ImageInsert

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor5

I am using CKEditor 5 and I need to prevent user to upload image to my server. I know it can be easily done by removing the corresponding module `Image`.

Here the catch, [`ImageInsert`](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/image.html#inserting-images-via-source-url) module looks good and I would like to use it for its ability to add image by URL. The problem is that `ImageInsert` button has an upload option by default. Is there any way to remove that option but keep the insert image by URL option?

[image: Insert image from URL]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible unless you modify [insert image plugin UI](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5/blob/master/packages/ckeditor5-image/src/imageinsert/imageinsertui.js) and custom build ckeditor5 by yourself.

---

There is a dirty fix (but not recommended)

```js
   ClassicEditor.create( document.querySelector( '#ckeditor' ))
    .then( editor => {
            window.editor = editor;

            const imageBtn = document.querySelector('.ck-file-dialog-button');
            if(!imageBtn) return;
            let imageIcon   = imageBtn.querySelector('svg.ck-icon');
            imageIcon.style.width = 'var(--ck-icon-size)';
            const dropdownBtn = document.querySelector('button.ck-splitbutton__arrow');
            let downAngleIcon = dropdownBtn.querySelector('svg.ck-icon');
            imageBtn.style.display = 'none';
            downAngleIcon.remove() 
            dropdownBtn.prepend(imageIcon);

    })
```

[image]

Comment: Why would you not recommend the second approch?

Comment: There is no issue with the second approach. However, it's not clean code, hard to maintain, `uploadImage` feature is still working at behind, I just hide it via Dom. And also the class names are static, they can be changed anytime when CKEditor upgrade their versions

Answer (score 1):

Just put
`{removePlugins: ['CKFinderUploadAdapter', 'CKFinder', 'EasyImage', 'Image', 'ImageCaption', 'ImageStyle', 'ImageToolbar', 'ImageUpload', 'MediaEmbed']}`
as second parameter of ClassicEditor.create() method.